# Project into a class with Private properties using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm using Entity Framework with a code-first approach to store data for a C# application I'm working with a SQL Server database. A challenge I'm currently running into involves a structure (approximately) like this:

```
public class MainEntity
{
    // Data
    public List<SubEntity> SubEntities { get; private set; }
}

public class SubEntity
{
    // More Data
    bool DoNotLoad { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I know that Entity Framework is able to "see" private property setters and populate the entities using reflection. That's why this works:

```
IEnumerable<MainEntity> Entities = MainEntities.Include(m => m.SubEntities).ToList();
```

And it will retrieve the `MainEntity` and all of its `SubEntities` from the database even though the setter for `SubEntities` is `private`.

I also know that Entity Framework supports more free-form projections, like so:

```
var projectedEntities = MainEntities.Select(m => 
    new {
        Main = m, 
        Sub = m.SubEntities.Where(s => !s.DoNotLoad)
    }
);
```

And then I'll have an anonymous type with the main entity and its sub entities, with a filter applied to the sub entities.

However, I would like to combine the two methods and end up with `MainEntity` objects that have their `SubEntity` property populated, but filtered.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
var invalidEntities = MainEntities.Select(m => 
    new MainEntity{
        SubEntities = m.SubEntities.Where(s => !s.DoNotLoad)
    }
);
```

C# doesn't let me use property initialization that way because `SubEntities` has a private setter, even though Entity Framework would work around that. Is there a way to make this work how I want it? My first priority is to avoid making two queries (e.g. get MainEntity, get filtered SubEntities, use specialized code to insert it), but I would also like to actually do the filtering in the database rather than getting everything and then filtering locally (e.g. `MainEntity.FilterSubEntities()`). Making the setter public isn't entirely impossible, but in order to use Property initialization I think I would need to change EVERY setter to public, which I would rather avoid.

I've been told that this is possible by projecting into an Anonymous type and if I name things in a certain way Entity Framework will "recognize" that it should project into `MainEntity` instead, but I haven't been able to find any references to this anywhere else. If that is possible then that would be my preferred method since it seems flexible enough to apply in various other situations where I need to filter in other ways.

Comment: EF6 does not allow you to project to entity class anyway. And applying OOP/domain/business logic/encapsulation to entity (store) models is totally wrong. They should be simple classes with all properties having public getters/setters. If you need domain logic, use separate model and mappings.

Answer (score 0):

#### I've found it

I've finally found an example of what I was told, and my testing indicates that it works. A few notes about the method:

- It does *not* work to arbitrarily project into private properties or properties with private setters. It only allows for more complex filtering of sub-entities, which fortunately was the primary use I was looking for.
- This *may* be undocumented behavior, or abuse of some other feature, so for all I know it could break at any time, and I can't necessarily state what would happen in any edge-cases that arise.
- I don't have any evidence that this is better by any metric than simply filtering locally, and it could be significantly worse. I haven't measured it, and I recognize that this seems to be "odd behavior" that might mess with Entity Framework's normal optimizations. I think it's pretty cool though.

With that out of the way, this is the technique using the sample classes described in the question:

```
var queryResult = MainEntities.Select(m => 
    new {
        MainEntity = m,
        m.SubEntities.Where(s => !s.DoNotLoad)
    })
    .ToList();
var finalList = queryResult.Select(q => q.MainEntity).ToList();
```

(Doing this on two lines and using a temporary variable isn't strictly necessary, but I think it clarifies that a DB query is executed at the first `ToList()` and then additional operations are applied locally.)

I believe that this works because Entity Framework populates navigation properties in a particularly eager manner. Essentially it populates the `SubEntities` List purely by adding every loaded `SubEntity` that has a foreign key to that `MainEntity`, regardless of what caused those entities to be loaded. That is speculation though, all I *definitely* know is that it currently works how I need it to.